# Base64 image not getting shown in internet explorer

Tags: python, html, image, internet-explorer, base64

I have a code to get base 64 form of an image like this:-

```
import base64
import requests
img=requests.get('https://example.com/hello.jpg')
base=base64.b64encode(img.content)
base=base.decode('utf-8')
print(base)
```

html:-

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<base64_data>" width="20" height="20">
```

I can get the base64  form of an image and can use them in browsers like chrome in html form. But in internet explorer I can only show some image. The image with short base64 are shown but in long it does not. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> But in internet explorer I can only show some image. The image with
>   short base64 are shown but in long it does not. How can I solve it?

Do you mean the image only display part, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emiwz.png)? I suppose perhaps the issue is related to the way you get the Image base64 string. You are getting the base64 string from the print result, right?

I have created a sample using your code, after set break point to check the `base` value and print result, it seems that the print() method only print part of base64 string. screenshot as below:

[image]

So, I suggest you could try to write the base64 string to a .txt file, and get the base64 string from it. Code as below:

```
import requests, base64, sys
from io import BytesIO
img=requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/eldOQ.jpg')
base=base64.b64encode(img.content)
base=base.decode('utf-8')
print("****************")
print(base)
print("****************")
text_file = open("output.txt", "w")
n = text_file.write(base)
text_file.close()
```

After using the whole base64 string, the result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHFQ0.png).

Comment: I mean the image with less base64 string length are shown in internet explorer. but long base64 string are not interpreted. Other browsers can do it perfectly.

Comment: Have you checked the value according to the above reply? Do you mean using the whole base64 string (long base64 string), it's still not working in IE browser? If that is the case, can you share the related base64 string or share the image?  (because, as you see in my previous reply, the code works well on my side)